# Change order of posts on facebook page wall?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to change the order of posts on a facebook page's wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Posts on a Page are always displayed in the order of the time they were posted. Newest first.

You can however change what you are looking at in terms of, just your page's posts or everyone's posts (people who LIKE the page).

This is done at the top of your Page's wall.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

You can however change the order of the posts on your main page. When you are directly at www.facebook.com you can select "Sort" somewhere at the top. You can choose to either show the top stories first, or the most recent.